# How to vertical-align dataTable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I am trying to vertical-align my dataTable, here is my table:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Town</th>
                <th>School</th>
                 <th>Degree</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>UK</td>
                 <td>London</td>
                  <td>Lorem</td>
                   <td>Phd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>UK</td>
                 <td>London</td>
                  <td>Lorem</td>
                   <td>Phd</td>
            </tr>
         
    </table>
</div>
```

What am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Instead of horizontal alignment, I want to achieve vertical alignment: Can I achieve something like that? I didn't find anything similar to this.

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: Apparenty you can't do it with dataTable: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23488/is-it-possible-to-render-datatabless-columns-horizontally

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/swqa1hc7/  but it's hacky at best and just useless at worse

Answer (score -1):

You can the table content to:

```
 <div class="container">
 <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td>Accountant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Office</th>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td>61</td>
    <td>63</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <td>2011/04/25</td>
    <td>2011/07/25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <td>$320,800</td>
    <td>$170,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Town</th>
    <td>London</td>
    <td>London</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>School</th>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Lorem</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Degree</th>
    <td>Phd</td>
    <td>Phd</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution will not work with dataTable